# How to show the outline for a cylinder without any post processing and using LineSegments?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wish to render a cylinder and only show it’s outline. I have tried using EdgeGeometry for this, but I’d like to not be able to see all the multiple lines that run across the lengths of the cylinder (I just need the outermost ends). I also do not want to apply any post processing for this due to certain constraints.

What I would like to see is the edges of the two caps of the cylinder and the two outermost edges running along its length, similar to the image shown below.

[Cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGYyl.png)

Is it possible to achieve this using LineSegments or something similar?

Tried using EdgesGeometry, but there were many unnecessary lines that ran across the length of the cylinder which I do not wish to display.